# How to emit data from an asycnhronous callback using Kotlin Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm starting to learn Kotlin Flow and Coroutines but I do not know how to make the code below works. What am I doing wrong?

```
interface MessagesListener {
    fun onNewMessageReceived(message: String)
}

fun messages(): Flow<String> = flow {

    val messagesListener = object : MessagesListener {
        override fun onNewMessageReceived(message: String) {

            // The line below generates the error 'Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body'

            emit(message)
        }
    }

    val messagesPublisher = MessagesPublisher(messagesListener)
    messagesPublisher.connect()
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use `callbackFlow` ....something like:

```
fun messages(): Flow<String> = callbackFlow {

    val messagesListener = object : MessagesListener {
        override fun onNewMessageReceived(message: String) {
            trySend(message)
        }
    }

    val messagesPublisher = MessagesPublisher(messagesListener)
    messagesPublisher.connect()
}
```

Comment: is there a way not having to use experimental apis? :)

Answer (score 8):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible because `emit` is a `suspend` function.

However, you can use [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) which is designed for such cases to convert Listeners/Callbacks into Coroutine's Flows.

```kotlin
fun messages() = callbackFlow<String> {
    val messagesListener = object : MessagesListener {
        override fun onNewMessageReceived(message: String) {
            trySend(message)
        }
    }
    val messagesPublisher = MessagesPublisher(messagesListener)
    messagesPublisher.connect()
}
```

Comment: `offer()` is deprecated.