# How to use callbackFlow within a flow?

Tags: kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to wrap a [`callbackFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) within an outer `flow` - there are items I'd like to emit from the outer flow, but I've got an old callback interface, which I'd like to adapt to Kotlin flow. I've looked at several [examples of usage of `callbackFlow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623712/how-to-emit-data-from-an-asycnhronous-callback-using-kotlin-flow) but I can't figure out how to properly trigger it within another flow.

Here's an example:

```kotlin
class Processor {
    fun start(processProgress: ProcessProgressListener) {
        processProgress.onFinished() //finishes as soon as it starts!
    }
}

interface ProcessProgressListener {
    fun onFinished()
}

//main method here:
 fun startProcess(processor: Processor): Flow<String> {
     val mainFlow = flow {
         emit("STARTED")
         emit("IN_PROGRESS")
     }

     return merge(processProgressFlow(processor), mainFlow)
 }

 fun processProgressFlow(processor: Processor) = callbackFlow {
     val listener = object : ProcessProgressListener {
         override fun onFinished() {
             trySend("FINISHED")
         }
     }

     processor.start(listener)
 }
```

The `Processor` takes a listener, which is triggered when the process has finished. When that happens, I would like to emit the final item `FINISHED`.

The way I invoke the whole flow is as follows:

```kotlin
     runBlocking {
         startProcess(Processor()).collect {
             print(it)
         }
     }
```

But, I get no output whatsoever. If I don't use the `megre` and only return the `mainFlow`, however, I do get the `STARTED` and `IN_PROGRESS` items though.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `awaitClose` in the end of `callbackFlow` block:

```
fun processProgressFlow(processor: Processor) = callbackFlow<String> {
    val listener = object : ProcessProgressListener {
        override fun onFinished() {
            trySend("FINISHED")
            channel.close()
        }
    }

    processor.start(listener)

    /*
     * Suspends until 'channel.close() or cancel()' is invoked
     * or flow collector is cancelled (e.g. by 'take(1)' or because a collector's coroutine was cancelled).
     * In both cases, callback will be properly unregistered.
     */
    awaitClose { /* unregister listener here */ }
}
```

`awaitClose {}` should be used in the end of `callbackFlow` block.
Otherwise, a callback/listener may leak in case of external cancellation.

According to the [`callbackFlow` docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html):

> `awaitClose` should be used to keep the flow running, otherwise the channel will be closed immediately when block completes. `awaitClose` argument is called either when a flow consumer cancels the flow collection or when a callback-based API invokes `SendChannel.close` manually and is typically used to cleanup the resources after the completion, e.g. unregister a callback. Using `awaitClose` **is mandatory** in order to prevent memory leaks when the flow collection is cancelled, otherwise the callback may keep running even when the flow collector is already completed. To avoid such leaks, this method throws `IllegalStateException` if block returns, but the channel is not closed yet.

Comment: I see, so I was effectively experiencing a memory leak, and that's why nothing was being printed out? This did the job by the way, thank you! Also just as a note - that of course means that I had to change the design of the `Processor` class - it has to be able to set/unset a listener, rather than taking the listener as an argument to `start`.

Comment: `IllegalStateException` was thrown, that's why nothing was printed.